# why do some experienced people have only 1 reputation

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, users

Why do some people who get a lot of reputation plusses(+), but still have only one point?
Example: [Your Common Sense](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285587/your-common-sense)

Comment: "This account is temporarily suspended for rule violations."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When a user's account is suspended it automatically shows just 1 reputation for them.

> Depending on the severity of the problem behavior — and at the complete discretion of the moderator — your account will be placed in timed suspension for anywhere from 1 to 365 days. That means:

> 

- Your account will be locked at 1 reputation.
- Your user page will have a visual indication that you are in timed suspension, and for how long.
- You will be unable to vote, ask, answer, or comment.

> At the end of this timed suspension period, your reputation will be recalculated, and your account will resume as normal.

> https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/

Comment: And before you stumble over that, yes, there are a few accounts with a deservedly much longer suspension. Those predate that blog-post.

Comment: @Deduplicator: no, they don't predate the blog post. It was just found that some people have been so disruptive to the community that the only remaining option was to use a long-term ban. The alternative would have been to nuke the account altogether.